# Create MediaWiki template to format source code

Tags: mediawiki, code, configuration

I want to create a MediaWiki template like

```
<syntaxhighlight lang="Java" style="background-color:lightgray; border:1px dashed gray;">
{{{code}}}
</syntaxhighlight>
```

and use it in normal article pages as

```
{{SourceCode|source=public static void main() {...}}}
```

but the problem is the `<syntaxhighlight></syntaxhighlight>` tags defeats `{{{code}}}` parameter, and the actual formatted result is

```
<syntaxhighlight lang="Java" style="background-color:lightgray; border:1px dashed gray;">
{{{code}}}
</syntaxhighlight>
```

instead of

```
<syntaxhighlight lang="Java" style="background-color:lightgray; border:1px dashed gray;">
public static void main() {...}
</syntaxhighlight>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that code inside “extension tags” like `<syntaxhighlight>` is not parsed, which is why the `{{{code}}}` is not replaced with the value of the `code` parameter.

What you need to use is to use `{{#tag}}` parser function:

```
{{#tag:syntaxhighlight|{{{code}}}|lang=java|style=background-color:lightgray; border:1px dashed gray;}}
```

Comment: This seems to work.

Comment: Another problem is if the instance of `code` happens to contain triple `{`, i.e. `{{{foobar}}}`, it does not handle correctly.

Comment: @Problemania That's normal for anything that's not considered code (and a parameter of a template is not considered code). To fix that, I think enclosing the code in `<nowiki>` should work, e.g. `{{SourceCode|source=<nowiki>{{{foobar}}}</nowiki>}}`.

Comment: How to incorporate `<nowiki>` into the template? I find that using just `{{#tag:syntaxhighlight|<nowiki>{{{code}}}</nowiki>|lang=java|style=background-color:lightgray; border:1px dashed gray;}}` does not quite work.

Comment: @Problemania I don't think you can.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that with `<includeonly>` tags, like so: (custom styles removed for clarity)

```
<includeonly><syntaxhighlight lang="Java"></includeonly>
{{{code}}}
<includeonly></syntaxhighlight></includeonly>
```

From [mediawiki.org](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Transclusion#Transclusion_markup):

> The markup `<includeonly>...</includeonly>` means that the text between the tags will only be used when the page is transcluded onto another page, and will not appear on the page itself.

So basically the `<syntaxhighlight>` tags are ignored on the template page, fooling the parser into highlighting code parameter when it is transcluded on another page.

Comment: The problem is not what the template page shows, but how does it transclude and this doesn't fix that.

Comment: @svick I'm not sure I understand. This does fix how the template transcludes, doing what the OP requested; what the template page shows doesn't matter. Also, I tested your code, and it seems to have the same problem as using regular tags.

Comment: I tested your code and it didn't work fo me. And as the documentation you included says, `<includeonly>` only affects the template page, not how it's transcluded.

Comment: @svick How are you testing it? It worked as expected for me. Perhaps you're confusing `<includeonly>` with `<noinclude>`, which doesn't affect the transclusion. Whatever is in `<includeonly>` tags is only included in a transclusion, not on the template page.

Comment: I copied your code verbatim to [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Svick/Sandbox2) and then transcluded it from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Svick/Sandbox).

Comment: Now that's odd. I tested the code earlier, and I swear it had worked fine.